# count element after load

Tags: jquery, string-length

I would like counting the total number of element on my page, after which the new element has been loaded.

At the beginning my nbrall function gives the right number. But after nbrall remains on the initial number

```
  setupLoadMore = function() {
        $('body').on('click','.loadmorebtn',function() {            
             var rubr = $(this).attr("data-id");
             var nbr =  $('.varnbr'+this.id).length;
             var nbrall = compteall();
             compteall();
             function compteall(){
                     nbrall =  $('.varnbrall').length;   
             }
            function postProcessing(data) {
             var myArray = data;
             var $item =  [];
             var $items = $(null); 
              $items =   $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                           $item[i] = $($($.parseHTML(val)));
                           $items = $items.add($item[i]);
                           $grid.append($items);
                           $grid.shuffle('appended', $items);
                           compteall;
                    });
            }

                getValues();
                function getValues(){
                  $.ajax({
                      url: '/?controller=pjMag&action=LoadMore',
                      type: 'POST',
                      data :   'rubr=' + rubr + '&nbr=' + nbr + '&nbrall=' + nbrall,
                      dataType : 'json',
                      cache : false,
                      success:postProcessing,
                      async : true
                   });
                };
        });
      },
```

I want updater value nbrall

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value to apply to the variable outside the function. So the only change is to put `return` in the function

```
 function compteall(){
     return $('.varnbrall').length;   
 }
```

Comment: and change compteall; to nbrall=compteall(); too

Comment: i have update, its same, https://jsfiddle.net/md1e6gkt/ it does not update the variable